# Delete own code in vba

Tags: vba

How would you delete your own vba project without a trace on a network? 
I don't know so I can't provide any code. 
This is a purely informative question.

Comment: This question is meaningless. There's absolutely no information, no actual question, and nothing to do with programming in it (the fact you used `vba` in the tag and text doesn't make it programming). There is no content that would make it useful to anyone at a later date. Voting to close as "not a real question".

Comment: What is the significance of "on a network" ?

Comment: What kind of information do you need? I think you very well understand. I don't know if it would be useful, but during a drunk night I realized that I just don't know. From my point of view, it Is just a question mark.

Comment: I got this question from a friend and didn't have an answer to it. Lame indeed; perhaps I will just delete the question afterwards.

Comment: I decided to delete the question without further notice  for I realize what a stupid question it is with no point. It was related to a political question, not appropriate for this forum. ApOlogies for drunkness and harassment. .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question has 2 parts

1. How would you delete your own vba project
2. Without a trace on a network

*Note*: I am taking the example of Excel VBA. Please navigate the menu accordingly and change the code accordingly.

**PART 1**

You can delete your own VBA project if `Trust Access To Visual Basics Project` is enabled.

To enable `Trust Access To Visual Basics Project`, do this

**EXCEL 2003 (doing this from memory)**

Click on Tools | Macro | Security | Trusted Sources and then click on `Trust access to the VBA project object model`

**EXCEL 2007 (doing this from memory)**

Click on Office Button | Excel Options | Trust Center | Trust Center Settings | Macro Settings and click on `Trust access to the VBA project object model`

**EXCEL 2010**

Go to File Tab | Options | Trust Center | Trust Center Settings | Macro Settings and click on `Trust access to the VBA project object model`

**CODE**

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteVBAPROJECT()
    Dim i As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    With ThisWorkbook.VBProject
        For i = .VBComponents.Count To 1 Step -1
            .VBComponents.Remove .VBComponents(i)
            .VBComponents(i).CodeModule.DeleteLines _
            1, .VBComponents(i).CodeModule.CountOfLines
        Next i
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

**PART 2**

I am not sure what do you mean by this.

If you mean is the IP recorded then I don't think so (I could be wrong here though)

If you mean the username is recorded of the user who last opened the file then yes it is recorded provided a username is fed into the system.

If you mean File properties like when the file was modified will be recorded then yes it will be recorded

Comment: +1 I eat my words and don't delete the post, the current project can be deleted indd. The network thing is related to recordings of multiple historical states of all files and folders on a network drive. Something which I can't see how to overrule from a simple vba project.

Comment: You cant do anything about it from VBA unfortunately. Also if the Sys Administrator takes a backup every day then this is definitely a lost cause :)

Comment: Too bad for the guy, lucky for the managers :-) I accept your reply.

Comment: +1 Nicely coded. Although be wary that a virus scanner may pick up and flag the code mutation technique (I can recall getting a bloodhund virus tag over similar code some years back)

Comment: Thanks :) I believe that could have been possible with I guess Norton 2006/07 as if I remember correctly, Norton used to embed itself in Office applications. Not sure if it still does...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helpful:

A method I use to strip all the Excel VBA code is to open the workbook with Excel 2007 or 2010.  Then save the workbook as an "xlsx" file, click "Yes" at the warning message.  Then close the workbook.  When you open it again, all VBA code is gone.