# Creating a self-deleting macro in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I'm trying to create a Macro in Excel 2007 that will delete itself when it finishes running and close Excel. The reason I want to do this is that I am going to be sending the Workbook out to other people, and I don't want them to see security warnings about the Macros. Several versions of this Workbook will be generated, so this I don't want to manually run and remove the Macro for each one.

I've tried the following code. It runs without error, but does not actually delete the Macro. If I remove the line "ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True" the Macro is deleted, but this prompts the user to save the Workbook as Excel closes. Is there any way to do this without User interaction?

```
Dim ActiveComponent
Set ActiveComponent = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ModuleName")
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove (ActiveComponent)
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.Quit
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

Comment: Why not just move your macros to another workbook and have them operate on the workbook(s) you're sending out?

Comment: Alternatively, you could have the macro create a copy of the workbook you are working in, delete the code from the copy, save, close and send it out.

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680411/delete-own-code-in-vba/11680865#11680865

Comment: Save as xlsx instead of xlsm?

Comment: @TimWilliams, your answer worked perfectly for me, thanks! If you add your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as Accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just move your macros to another workbook and have them operate on the workbook(s) you're sending out?