# deactivate/comment out makros in a lot of excel files

Tags: excel, vba

i do have several hundred of excel files. Every excel file contains a makro in the "workbooks_open" method. I want to open all these files, comment out the code, save and close the file.

a loop through all files with open/close is not a problem, but with the changing of the vba code i have no idea.

many thanks in advance!

```
Sub test()

Dim Path as string = "C:\123\"
Dim cDir As String
cDir = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")
   
Do While cDir <> ""


       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
       
           '### open
           Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & cDir


           '### here i want to deactivate/comment out the makro in the workbook_open method
         
            
            '### save
            ActiveWorkbook.Save
            ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
    
            '### close
            ActiveWorkbook.Close False
       
        cDir = Dir
Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: Please, show us what you have. Even the iteration between the workbooks and opening them. Are all the workbooks in discussion located in the same folder? It is mandatory to prove that you did something (at least, researching) to accomplish what you need...

Comment: i've inserted the code above. Yes the files are all located in the same folder.

Comment: @Hias There have been further answers you might be interested in as they show partly different & shorter approaches. - *Consider upvoting if you found them helpful, well researched or instructive.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the code of a workbook using code, you need to allow access to the VBE via code - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11680865/7599798 how to do so.

- You access all the coding stuff of a workbook using its `VBProject`-Property.
- If you want to use the Types and Constants of the Project, add a reference to `Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility`
- The VBProject contains a collection of Components `VBComponents`, this is the list you see in the VBE in the project window, it contains all modules, classes and forms.
- The Workbook-Module has the Name `ThisWorkbook` and it's type = 100 (use `vbext_ct_Document` if you have added the mentioned reference)
- To access the code of a module, use the property `CodeModule` of the component.
- The lines of code can be fetched using the `lines`-property of CodeModule, you need to pass two parameters (startrow and numbers of rows).
- The lines-property is read only, if you want to change code, you can use the methods `InsertLines`, `DeleteLines` and `ReplaceLines`

Have a look to the next routine to see how it could look like. It will simply replace the `Workbook_Open()`-routine with `Workbook_Open_BACKUP()` so it will no longer fire when the workbook is opened.

```
Sub RemoveOnOpen(wb As Workbook)
    Dim i As Long

    With wb.VBProject
        For i = 1 to .VBComponents.Count 
            ' Debug.Print .VBComponents(i).Type, .VBComponents(i).Name
            If .VBComponents(i).Type = vbext_ct_Document And .VBComponents(i).Name = "ThisWorkbook" Then
                Dim row As Long
                For row = 1 To .VBComponents(i).CodeModule.CountOfLines
                    Dim module As CodeModule, line As String
                    Set module = .VBComponents(i).CodeModule
                    line = Trim(module.Lines(row, 1))

                    If Left(line, 27) = "Private Sub Workbook_Open()" Then
                        module.ReplaceLine row, Replace(line, "Workbook_Open()", "Workbook_Open_BACKUP()")
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**Update**: As T.M. noted, the name of the Workbook module may be different if used in a different language environment, you should check this.
I also added a `Trim`-statement when checking the code line for the Sub.

Comment: Couple of hints: a) .`VBComponents.Item(i).Name` depends on regional settings, in German it would be *"DieseArbeitsmappe"* instead of *"ThisWorkbook"*. - Didn't test, but I tend to assume it *is* `Item(1)`? b) The fixed position check `If Left(line, 27) = "Private Sub Workbook_Open()" Then` seems to be dangerous as the Sub procedure might be indented (e.g. prefixed by one or more blanks). @FunThomas

Comment: @T.M. Thanks for the hints. a) Didn't know that the name is language dependent (although I am german, I prefer to have an english version as the names and terms in german are *horrible*. I am not sure if the Workbook object is always the first, but as the type 100 is only valid for Workbook and Sheets, it's maybe sufficient to check for the type - a Worksheet module shouldn't have a `Workbook_Open` routine.  b) I think a simple `Trim` will do the trick (I would never indent a Sub-Statement, it even didn't came to my mind...)

Comment: Fyi *Digesting* the question how to reference `ThisWorkbook` I found a language independant way with the additional benefit of a direct row search without line loops. @FunThomas

Answer (score 2):

Please, use the next `Sub`. It should be called by the code iterating between all workbooks to be changed:

```
Sub ComSpecSub(wb As Workbook, moduleName As String, strLine As String)
    Dim objThisWb As VBComponent, CodeM As CodeModule, i As Long, j As Long
    Set objThisWb = wb.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook")
    Set CodeM = objThisWb.CodeModule
     If CodeM.Find(strLine, 1, 1, CodeM.CountOfLines, 1, False) = True Then
        For i = 1 To CodeM.CountOfLines
            If InStr(CodeM.lines(i, 1), strLine) > 0 Then
                If left(CodeM.lines(i, 1), 1) = "'" Then Exit Sub 'already commented...
                                                                  'if running the code again
                Do While i + j <= CodeM.CountOfLines
                    CodeM.ReplaceLine i + j, "'" & CodeM.lines(i + j, 1)
                    If InStr(CodeM.lines(i + j, 1), "End Sub") > 0 Then Exit Do
                    j = j + 1
                Loop
            End If
        Next i
     End If
End Sub
```

The above code needs a reference to 'Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility'
It should be called from your code as:

```
ComSpecSub ActiveWorkbook, "ThisWorkbook", "Private Sub Workbook_Open()"
    ActiveWorkbook.Close True
```

If adding the required reference looks problematic, please firstly run the next code, which will add it automatically:

```
Sub addExtenssibilityReference()
   'Add a reference to 'Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibilty 5.3':
   ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid _
        GUID:="{0002E157-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", _
        Major:=5, Minor:=3
End Sub
```

Comment: Fine solution. - Side notes fyi: Similar hints as in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70783156/deactivate-comment-out-makros-in-a-lot-of-excel-files/70783908#comment125147271_70783908) above: ad a) regional setting, ad b) `If left(CodeM.lines(i, 1), 1) = "'"` assumes that the outcommented code has been changed exclusively by `ComSpecSub` without later blank prefixes or even a later addition of a completely new sub below. @FaneDuru

Comment: @T.M. This was the checking purpose, to check if the code has already been run... Otherwise, if the "'" is not the first character, the code will run and place another one. I must confess that I never needed such a procedure... I imagined it now in this way and I can admit that it may not be the optimum way. I am open to any better version. I more like learning than being right.

Comment: Like the addition of an `addExtenssibilityReference()` procedure as a very practical help!  - fyi posted a language independant approach without line loops @FaneDuru

Answer (score 2):

**Language independant & no loops**

In addition to the valid answers of *@FunThomas* *(following his renaming idea)* and *@FaneDuru* I demonstrate an approach with two benefits:

- the component `ThisWorkbook` can be found independantly from **regional language settings** via `wb.VBProject.VBComponents(wb.CodeName)`,
  as workbooks can be referenced not only by their name string which may differ for other languages than English,
  but also via a workbook's `wb.CodeName` property *(similar for sheets)*;
- the **effective procedure start row** can be found *in one go* via
  `.ProcBodyLine(srchProcName, 0)`, where the zero input defines a sub or function *procedure kind* (other than Get|Let|Set props);

**Further hints:**

Needs a library reference to `Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3` *(c.f. also @FaneDuru's progamatical approach).*

*Generally replacing a code line by another should consider possible line breaks ( `_`) resulting in two or several lines, too; due to the brevity of the procedure I don't assume a line break before `"Workbook_Open"` (like e.g. `Private Sub _".*

```
Sub BackUp(wb as WorkBook, Optional ByVal srchProcName As String = "Workbook_Open")
'Purp: change a given procedures name in ThisWorkbook (e.g. "Workbook_Open") by adding "_BACKUP"
'0) Define backup name string
    Dim backupName  As String: backupName = srchProcName & "_BACKUP"
    
'1) Access ThisWorkbook directly by its CodeName (independant from regional language settings)!
    Dim myComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Set myComp = wb.VBProject.VBComponents(wb.CodeName)
    'Debug.Print "** Code(Name): " & wb.CodeName & " (Local Name: " & myComp.Name & ")"

'2) Search directly for the effective start row of srchProcName (e.g. "Workbook_Open")
    Dim effectiveRow As Long
    With myComp.CodeModule                              ' the component's code module
        On Error Resume Next
        effectiveRow = .ProcBodyLine(srchProcName, 0)   ' find effective row of search procedure
        Select Case Err.Number
        Case 0
            Dim newContent As String
            newContent = Replace(Trim(.Lines(effectiveRow, 1)), srchProcName, backupName)
            .ReplaceLine effectiveRow, newContent
            Debug.Print "** " & wb.Name & vbNewLine & "" _
                        ; "   Changed procedure '" & srchProcName & "' in row " & effectiveRow & _
                        " to " & backupName
        Case 35
            Debug.Print "** " & wb.Name & vbNewLine & _
                        "   Error " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description & vbNewLine & _
                        "   Procedure '" & srchProcName & "' doesn't exist!" & vbNewLine & _
                        "   (Possibly already 'backupped')": Err.Clear
        Case Else
            Debug.Print "** " & wb.Name & vbNewLine & _
                        "   Error " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description: Err.Clear
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

**Example output in VB Editor's immeditate window**

Inserting `Backup ActiveWorkbook` or a pre-set `Backup wb` in your code should suffice to rename existing "Workbook_Open" procedures by a "_BACKUP" suffix.

```
** ExampleWorkbook147.xlsm
   Changed procedure 'Workbook_Open' in row 8 to Workbook_Open_BACKUP
```

Comment: I haven't even heard about workbook `CodeName`. I also did not know that Excel localizes `ThisWorkbook` name, too... Interesting, voted it up. I think I can find a even more static (no iteration) solution using `Find`. I remembered I used it sometimes, even if I very seldom did that. In fact, it was about of a challenge to find such a solution. I think I answered here trying to clarify somebody else code. The basic idea is that `Find`, even if it returns a boolean, it also change the `StartLine` parameter, returning it for the found line. I will rapidly prepare such an answer, too....

Comment: Note that ProcBodyLine has the benefit that it returns the *actual* (header) starting line of a procedure (here: `effectiveRow`) without need to check for an additional `"Sub "` or `"Private Sub `" line token if searched by text comparison. *I should mention a further caveat regarding line-breaks via ` _` , too.* @FaneDuru

Answer (score 2):

In reply of @T.M comment and nice answer:

The next solution uses `Find`, which besides returning `True` when the searched string has been found, it modifies the `StartLine` parameter, if used as a variable. Then, since the question also involves commenting all the procedure lines, not only changing the declaration line, it will do it, without iteration, too:

```
Sub findProcThisWb(Optional wb As Workbook, Optional strLine As String = "Workbook_Open")
    Dim thisWBCodeM As CodeModule, foundLine As Long, ProcExists As Boolean, arrPr
    Dim procName As String, strCodeLine As String, strProcedure As String, strComProc As String
    
    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set thisWBCodeM = wb.VBProject.VBComponents(wb.CodeName).CodeModule
    foundLine = 1             'initialize the line where from Find starts searching
    Dim noLines As Long    'it will keep the found procedure number of lines
    With thisWBCodeM
'       ProcExists = .Find(strLine, foundLine, .CountOfLines, 1, -1, False, False) ' OP
        ProcExists = .Find(strLine, foundLine, 1, .CountOfLines, -1, False, False) ' << Edit/2022-01-24 corr. argument order

        Debug.Print foundLine: ' the line of the found procedure, if it has been found!
        If ProcExists Then
            strCodeLine = .lines(foundLine, 1)  'return the whole line
            Debug.Print strCodeLine               'the whole line where the searched string has been found

            procName = .ProcOfLine(foundLine, vbext_pk_Proc):    Debug.Print "Proc name = " & procName
            noLines = .ProcCountLines(procName, vbext_pk_Proc): Debug.Print "Number of procedure lines = " & noLines
            strProcedure = .lines(foundLine, noLines): Debug.Print "The whole procedure:" & vbLf & strProcedure
            arrPr = Split(strProcedure, vbLf)
              strComProc = "'" & Join(arrPr, vbLf & "'"): Debug.Print "The whole commented procedure:" & vbLf; strComProc

            'Delete the actual procedure lines:
            .DeleteLines foundLine, noLines - 1 ' Edit 2022-01-24: -1
            'Add the commented procedure code (from string, but not in the same place, after the declaration lines):
            .AddFromString strComProc
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Admiring your professional flair (not to speak from your late-night workload) allow me some hints though: 1) the 2nd argument in the proc call has to be `Optional strLine As String = "Workbook_Open"` to avoid crashing with an empty strLine; 2) the arguments order in `.Find` has to be `ProcExists = .Find(strLine, foundLine, 1, .CountOfLines, -1, False, False)` where I'd prefer a minus 1 argument for the `EndCol` param; 3) imo `.DeleteLines foundLine, noLines - 1` needs a minus 1 to not include the following  proc block. @FaneDuru

Comment: @T.M. If the `Sub` should be specifically created for that event, yes, it certainly should be as you suggest. In fact, placed it as `Optional` only to have the first one `Optional`, too. I was thinking to check in the code if it is a null string, send a message and exiting. But it was very late in my country...
 Anyhow, your suggestion does not bother using it for any others. I will edit the answer and follow the suggestion. I do not understand why `-1` will be better, but I trust you and try using it in the same way...:) I initially tried using a variable for column, too, but not updated...

Comment: @T.M. I will explore the `-1` column meaning a little later. Now I am watching a tennis match from Oustralian Open...

Comment: a) see [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/find-method-vba-add-in-object-model]: 
*"EndCol|EndLine: Required. A Long specifying the last column|line of the match if one is found.The last column may be designated as -1*.; 
b) `ProcExists = .Find(strLine, startline:=foundLine, startColumn:=1, Endline:=.CountOfLines, EndColumn:=-1)`, so imo the right order is 1 **before** .CountOfLines if not addressed explicitly as `Endline:=...`; c) Enjoy Melbourne :-; @FaneDuru

Comment: @T.M. It's a problem with the link you tried. I think, you placed the URL between []... Thanks! I am following the match Cirstea vs. Pavlyuchenkova. My favorite looks to play well.

Comment: I took the liberty to correct the wrong argument order of `.Find(...) *(see  the `ProcExists = ` assignment after `With thisWBCodeM`)*. - *Btw Cirstea played well.*

Comment: @T.M. It plays well even now. But Iga is a great player...